# Java GC: does it ever make sense to call super.finalize() in a class that only extends Object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

There is much discussion on calling `super.finalize()` when a class extends another non-Object class. But what about a class that only implicitly extends Object - is there any functional effect? If there is no effect, is this just good defensive programming in case someone decides to make that class explicitly subclass a non-Object class?

Comment: In a word, yes, it is defensive. If all finalizers call `super.finalize()` (in their own `finally` blocks), none of them can be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs of [`finalize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) method

> The finalize method of class Object performs no special action; it simply returns normally. Subclasses of Object may override this definition.

Comment: And for  - *is this just good defensive programming in case someone decides to make that class explicitly subclass a non-Object class* - Yes, you should explicitly call `super.finalize()` to ensure that GC happens properly. This is not overly defensive. :)

Comment: First you say "to ensure that GC happens properly" then you say "This is not overly defensive." I'm confused - if this is not defensive, then what is it? Defensive means to me you're preventing something from happening like future code written that mistakenly causes an issue, but "to ensure that GC happens properly" implies that making this call has an actual direct effect with a system with the current code. Unless you mean ensure in the spirit of prevention of a future threat as opposed to a current imminent threat.